# How to disable the "Updates Available" warnings on a Mac

Tags: macos, updates

My MacBook continually reminds me that there are updates available for applications that I don't intend to update. So the crux of my question is basically this:

How does one hide these "available updates" reminders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

goto `System Preferences - Software Update` and turn off Automatically check for updates:

[image]

Comment: note in mavericks this is under the `app store` option in system preferences.

Answer (score 0):

or if you prefer the command line, you can also use

```
sudo softwareupdate --schedule off
```

This will do the same thing without the GUI.  This can be embedded in a deployment script for re-use.